# Send Array of Objects from JavaScript to C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying several ways to pass the list of objects to the controller but 
the controller always receives `null`

Here is my code:

**View:**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

       var arrPropIdPos = new Array();         

        $('.property').each(function () {
            var obj = {
                PropertyId : $(this).attr('PropertyId'),
                Xposition : $(this).attr('xPos'),
                Yposition : $(this).attr('yPos')

            };
            arrPropIdPos.push(obj);
        });

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arrPropIdPos);


       $.ajax({
           url: "/PropertyPosition/Insert/",
           type: 'POST',         
           data: jsonData,
           dataType: 'json',
           //...                
        },
```

**console.log(arrPropIdPos);**

```
0: Object
 PropertyId: "1"
 Xposition: "11"
 Yposition: "55"
__proto__:  Object

1: Object
 PropertyId: "2"
 Xposition: "651"
 Yposition: "48"
__proto__:  Object
```

**console.log(jsonData);**

```
[{"PropertyId":"1","Xposition":"11","Yposition":"55"},
{"PropertyId":"2","Xposition":"651","Yposition":"48"}]
```

**Controller (option 1):**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Insert(string jsonData)
{
  // jsonData is null
}
```

**Controller (option 2):**

```
  public class PropertyPositionInsert
    {
        public string PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Xposition { get; set; }
        public string Yposition { get; set; }
    }

   public JsonResult Insert(List<PropertyPositionInsert> model)
    {
      // model is null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function () {

    var arrPropIdPos = new Array();

    $('.property').each(function () {

        var obj = {
             'PropertyId' : $(this).attr('PropertyId')
            ,'Xposition' : $(this).attr('xPos')
            ,'Yposition' : $(this).attr('yPos')

        };

        arrPropIdPos.push(obj);
    });    
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(arrPropIdPos),
            url: "/PropertyPosition/Insert/"                                    
        });
```

**Class:**

```
  public class PropertyPositionInsert
    {
        public string PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Xposition { get; set; }
        public string Yposition { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**:

```
 public JsonResult Insert(PropertyPositionInsert[] model)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your array into an object with a property model:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({model: arrPropIdPos});
```

Also try to set dataType option to 'application/json'.

Comment: it works with array. but my array is a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this in the past and have found that if you set

```
traditional: true
```

in your jQuery ajax call, it shjould fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

   var arrPropIdPos = new Array();         

    $('.property').each(function () {
        var obj = {
            PropertyId : $(this).attr('PropertyId'),
            Xposition : $(this).attr('xPos'),
            Yposition : $(this).attr('yPos')

        };
        arrPropIdPos.push(obj);
    });

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arrPropIdPos);


    $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {  
    },
    type: "POST",
   "async": true,
    url: "/PropertyPosition/Insert/",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {

    },
    complete: function () {
              },

})
```

**Controller:**
Create a class or model

```
public class PropertyPositionInsert
{
    public string PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Xposition { get; set; }
    public string Yposition { get; set; }
}
public IHttpActionResult JsonResult (PropertyPositionInsert obj)
{
 obj.PropertyId;
 obj.Xposition ;
 obj.Yposition; 
}
```

you can check the values in above obj